# Integration by Parts Sin Cos

Tags: integration

I'm trying to figure out how to integrate by parts.  I'm not sure where I should start.
I need to show my $'u$, $du$, $dv$, and $v'$.

$x\left(2\sin\left(x\right)+x\cos\left(x\right)\right)$

Comment: Consider all possible factors that you are able to integrate immediately:  $x$ or, splitting the sum, $x$ or $2\sin(x)$, $x$ or $x^2$ or $\cos(x)$.

Comment: This looks like the kind of thing you'd want to expand out first -- $2x\sin x + x^2\cos x$ -- though that actually I can do in my head and it's not by parts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: polynomials gets simpler and simpler when you differentiate them.

Hint 2: $\int A(x)+B(x) dx = \int A(x) dx + \int B(x) dx$

Comment: And you can add that the trigonometric functions do neither simplify nor complexify.

Comment: that is a good point!

Comment: I think I got the answer, x² sin (x)

Comment: congratulations! plus constant too.

Comment: Now I need to revolve this around the x-axis from 0-2. $π[x(2sinx+xcosx)]²$

Comment: erm... square it, then integrate it from 0 to 2, then multiply it by $\pi$? Double angle formula might be helpful.

Comment: After squaring it and expanding the expression, you  should obtain three terms, of which we should be able to convert each term to a product of polynomial multiplied with a trigonometry function using double angle formula.